# "grin at" vs "grin to"

Tags: prepositions, difference

What's the difference between "grin at" and "grin to"?

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grin_1) ("Extra Examples"):
**(1)** *She grinned **to** herself at the thought*.
my variant:
**(2)** *She grinned **at** herself at the thought*.
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grin_1):
**(3)** *She grinned amiably **at** us*.
my variant:
**(4)** *She grinned amiably **to** us*.
What's the difference between (3) and (4)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, **[to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to)** can mean

> in the direction of
> used for showing who receives something or who experiences an action

and **[at](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at)** can mean

> in the direction of

The direction of a grin is outward- in the direction that you are looking-  so you could use both words with the sense "in the direction of" when you are grinning at/to some other person.

When the recipient of the grin is yourself, you can use a mirror to grin **at** yourself, but if you don't have a mirror, only the "who receives or experiences an action" applies, and only **to** has that meaning.

That said, [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grinned%20at%20herself%2Cgrinned%20to%20herself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) does find a small number of **grinned at herself** that don't involve a mirror, for example:

> It worked: Effie grinned at herself in satisfaction. - *In-the-bye stories, William Flewelling, 2018*

To answer your specific questions, in my opinion 1 is preferable to 2, whereas 3 and 4 are identical in meaning.

Comment: I don't think 4) is really acceptable in English.

Comment: @Lambie I think "not really acceptable" is going a bit far: it's hardly going to raise eyebrows.. In my opinion it's grammatically correct but not idiomatic... and very uncommon.

Comment: Well, grammatically correct but not idiomatic is not really correct and would be edited. We just don't say to grin to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the word I would use with directing facial expressions to somebody is *at*:

> She grinned/smiled/frowned/pouted at me.

*To* is also possible, but to me it seems much less likely. I would interpret it as meaning that there was more intention there: not just that I was the person she grinned etc at, but that she was trying to convey something to me by doing so.

(Note that this does not apply to other gestures: we say *she nodded/waved/beckoned **to** me*, rather than *at me*).

However, these expressions have another possible argument, the event or stimulus, and for that we normally use *at*:

> She grinned/smiled/frowned/pouted at the interruption.

If we are using that "at" (as in your 1. and 2.) then I think *to* is more likely for the person the expression is directed at:

> She grinned/smiled/frowned/pouted to me at the thought.